# How do I create a (1000, 500) array from an (1000, 1) and indexing trough n values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to make my variables phi, En, and Cn into appropriate sizes arrays. I was able to do this successfully in Matlab by the conversion from Matlab to python is difficult. How would I go about this calculation. I would essentially need the entire array of x to be multiplied when n = 1, again when n = 2, ..., n = 500 and get the correct sized arrays for En and Cn as well.

```
def Gaussan_wave_packet():

    quantum_number = 500
    x = np.linspace(0,100,1000).astype(complex)
    x0 = 50, a = 10, l = 1
    A = (1/(4*a**2))**(1/4.0)
    m = 0.511*10**6 #mass
    hbar = 6.58211951*10**(-16)
    L = x[-1]

    #Gaussian wave packet
    psi_x0 = np.exp((-(x - x0)**2)/(4*a**2))*np.exp(1j*l*x)

    #Normalize wave function
    A = (1/(np.sqrt(np.trapz((np.conj(psi_x0)*psi_x0),x))))
    psi_x0_normalized = np.outer(psi_x0,A) # Makes a (1000,1) array

    phi_result  = np.array([])
    En_result = np.array([])
    Cn_result = np.array([])

    for n in range(0,quantum_number):

        phi = ( np.sqrt( 2/L ) * np.sin( ( n * x * np.pi )/L ) ) # Needs to be (1000,500)
        En = ( ( np.power(n,2))*(np.pi**2)*(hbar**2))/(2*m*L**2) # Needs to be (1,500)
        Cn = np.trapz( ( np.conj(phi) * psi_x0_normalized ), x ) # Needs to be (1,500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use element wise multiplication with `np.multiply(a,b)`.
And reshape `x`in order to use implicit expansion and to avoid a for loop:

```
n = np.arange(quantum_number)
phi =  np.sqrt(2/L) * np.sin((np.multiply(n,x.reshape(1000,1)*np.pi)/L ))
```

You can apply the same logic to `En` and `Cn`.

The matlab equivalent would be:

```
n = 0:(quantum_number-1);
phi = (2/L)^0.5*sin(n.*x.'*pi/L);
```

Comment: It worked thank you! However, I am still unable to figure out how Cn works. I get this error back   Cn = np.trapz( ( np.multiply(np.conj(phi), psi_x0_normalized)), x.reshape(len(x),1)) # Needs to be (1,500)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3890, in trapz
    ret = add.reduce(d * (y[tuple(slice1)]+y[tuple(slice2)])/2.0, axis)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,0) (1000,499). From this line: Cn = np.trapz( ( np.multiply(np.conj(phi), psi_x0_normalized)), x.reshape(len(x),1)). I believe it has to do with trapz.